# ChartJS Line Charts - remove color underneath lines

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js

Okay, so I have a ChartJS line chart working that populates directly from data coming for my db.
What I need now is to get rid of the color underneath each of the lines. [as seen in the screenshot below].

[image: Example of Graph]

Here's my HTML:

```
<div ng-if="hasData">
    <canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line" data="data" labels="labels" legend="true" series="series" options="options" click="onClick"></canvas>
<div>
```

Here's My JS:

```
            scope.labels = ['02:00','04:00','06:00', '08:00', '10:00', '12:00','14:00', '16:00', '18:00', '20:00', '22:00'];
            scope.series = series;
            scope.data = [volumesSelectedDate, volumesPeakDate, volumesModelCapacity];
            
                            
            scope.options = {
                scaleOverride: true,
                scaleStartValue: 0,
                scaleSteps: 11,
                scaleStepWidth: 6910,
            }
            
            scope.loadingDailyAppVolumes = false;
            scope.hasData = true;
            
            
        };
        scope.onClick = function (points, evt) {
            //console.log(points, evt);
        };
```

So, how would I go about this?
Also, how would I go about manually setting the color for each line?

Example:

selected date: blue,
peak date: yellow,
model capacity: grey.

Thanks.

Answer (score 125):

Check [this section](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html#dataset-properties) on the Chart.js docs. Set the `fill` property to false within your dataset configuration:

```
var data = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [{
        label: "My First dataset",
        fill: false,
        data: [1, 2, 3]
    }]
};
```

Specify an array to the `borderColor` property if you want each line to have a different stroke color:

```
var myColors = ['red', 'green', 'blue']; // Define your colors

var data = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [{
        label: "My First dataset",
        fill: false,
        borderColor: myColors
        data: [1, 2, 3]
    }]
};
```

Comment: Okay, but my setup for each chart is different. I don't have a dataset config.

Comment: ...and what is this different setup? Do you use some angular plugin for chart.js? Did you create a custom code?

Comment: @LinusBorg I wonder too. Couldn't find anything in the docs about that particular setup.

Comment: I am a contributor to Chart.js and the code in the question is not from the core library.

Answer (score 35):

Below solution was working when integrated chart js with Angular

```
$scope.options = {
                    scales: {
                      yAxes: [
                        {
                          id: 'y-axis-1',
                          type: 'linear',
                          display: true,
                          position: 'left'
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    elements: {
                        line: {
                                fill: false
                        }
                    }
                };

<canvas id="" class="col-sm-12 chart chart-line" chart-data="data"
                            chart-options="options" chart-colors="colors">
</canvas>
```

Answer (score 11):

Just set the fill option to be false in the datasets options:

```
data: {
   datasets: [{
      label: "",
      data: dataPoints,
      borderColor: color ,
      fill:false //this for not fill the color underneath the line
                                }]
                            },
```

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:

```
$scope.color = [{
                  backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                  borderColor: '#F78511',
                },];
```

Answer (score 6):

I solved this issue.

First step. html element inner add <- chart-colors="colors"
 like this :

```
<canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line" data="data" labels="labels" chart-colors="colors" legend="true" series="series" options="options" click="onClick"></canvas>
```

second step. $scope val colors Add
like this :

```
$scope.colors = [{
        backgroundColor : '#0062ff',
        pointBackgroundColor: '#0062ff',
        pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#0062ff',
        borderColor: '#0062ff',
        pointBorderColor: '#0062ff',
        pointHoverBorderColor: '#0062ff',
        fill: false /* this option hide background-color */
    }, '#00ADF9', '#FDB45C', '#46BFBD'];
```

good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, using angular-chart.js and got the desired result with:

```
$scope.override = {
    fill: false
};
```

and

```
<canvas class="chart chart-line" 
    chart-dataset-override="override"
    chart-data="data">
</canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

just tweak ts file to include ::

```
chartOptions = {
scales: { xAxes: [{}],  yAxes: [{}] },
elements: { line: { fill: false } }
};
```

html file looking as ::

```
<div style="display: block; width: 500px; height: 400px;">
<canvas
  baseChart
  [chartType]="'line'"
  [datasets]="chartData"
  [labels]="chartLabels"
  [colors]="lineChartColors"
  [options]="chartOptions"
  [legend]="true"
  (chartClick)="onChartClick($event)">
</canvas>
</div>
```

**This will Work**

Answer (score 1):

Set `fill:` value `false`

```js
let chart = new Chart('myChart', {

type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            fill: false, // <-- Here
        }]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        scales: {
            y: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.6.2/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```